# How should I abstract my business level classes when I have multiple implementations of Unit-Of-Work?

Tags: dependency-injection

I'm trying to create a business logic class called **Products**, where I pass in a unit-of-work (this unit-of-work is created via dependency injection):

```
var products = new Products(uow); //uow implements IUnitOfWork
```

Products has a method called **Add**

```
int newID = products.Add("my widget");
```

Now assume I have two implementations for IUnitOfWork, **SqlServer** and **InMemoryMock**.  The business logic for all methods of the **Products** class is basically the same, however in some instances the inner workings changes based upon the persistence, or in this case which implementation of IUnitWork is used.  Let's assume that the **Add** method is one of those cases.

In order to have different implementations, I could make Products an abstract class, and then inherit from that and make the **Add** method abstract and force the implementations to override this method.

However this would require me to create some sort of ProductFactory, which would return the correct class:

```
var products = ProdcutFactory.Get(uow); //return the SqlServer or InMemoryMock version
```

This would require my application to reference the assembly which has ProductFactory, which in turn has a reference to both the SqlServer and InMemoryMock assemblies.  Which according to Mark Seemann's incredible book, this is a no-no.

Is there a better way to accomplish my abstraction attempt?  (Is there a way to ping Mark Seemann?  I know he is active on S.O.)

EDIT:

For my SqlServer implementation, I need to actually save (not commit) my added row in order to get the new row's ID to return it to the consumer (MVC controller).  So my SqlServer implementation of **Products** will have this extra call.  My MVC controller shouldn't care which type of **Products** class it uses.

I'm trying to find a way of creating a **Products** class that matches the type of IUnitOfWork passed into the controller. **My concern is that my MVC project shouldn't have a reference to my InMemoryMock implementations**.

Is the use of an AbstractFactory referenced in Mark's book (page?)  I'm starting to get the feeling that the DI container would pass in this factory.

EDIT #2:
Let's say that my **Add** method has to insert a row using the repository to my Sql database, and the ID column for the associated table is an auto-incrementing column.  I then need that ID for a subsequent operation.  The only way I can get that value is to call the Save method on IUnitOfWork (well, I could call Commit, but I don't want to commit just yet)

```
uow.ProductRepo.Insert(new UserModel(){.....
uow.Save();
var uid = uow.ProductRepo.Get(u => u.someuniquecode == someUniqueCode)....... (etc)
```

Now if I were doing the Mock version, I wouldn't need to call the Save method on the UOW, but I would rather supply the ID during the insert.

```
var uid = uow.ProductRepo.Get(some lambda to get the largest ID) + 1
uow.ProductRepo.Insert(new UserModel(ID = uid, .......
```

So I basically have two versions of **Add**, each doing something similar but in different ways that my consumer has no interest in whatsoever.

---

I'm creating my UOW (which contain repos) via dependency injection.  I've created some "Clerk" classes that take the UOW and they perform the business functions.  The business logic is the same regardless of my UOW type (which is really based upon the repository type), however there are slight differences with how the repositories work, notably the auto-increment index feature.

What I have done is create an abstract business class called **Products** which implements IProductClerk (which itself implements IDisposable) and put the meat of my business logic there.  I have two separate libraries (business.mock and business.sqlserver) where I implement this abstract class and **override** any methods that can't use the "standard" logic.  My consumers get instances of IProductClerk, so both implementations look the same (hopefully this satisfies LSP).

I also have an IProductClerkFactory interface, and in my business.mock and business.sqlserver classes, I created **ProductClerkFactory : IProductClerkFactory** which return their implementation of IProductClerk.

In my controllers that need IProductClerk, I add **IProductClerkFactory productClerkFactory** to the constructor and then in my composition root I configure IProductClerkFactory should use the business.sqlserver.clerk.ProuctClerkFactory.

When my controller is called, I get the correct type of IProductClerkFactory (which my consumer doesn't care about), which from there I can generate a IProductClerk and pass in the persistence dependency (unit of work).

For my unit tests I create an instance of the factory from the mock library, and for integration tests I use the sql library.

How does this look?

Comment: Not sure I understand the entire question, but couldn't you define an Abstract Factory (`IProductFactory`)?

Comment: lol.  I just sent you an email.  Let me edit my question now.

Comment: Still not sure I understand. Some of the things you write (e.g. "in some instances the inner workings changes based upon the persistence") sounds like `Products` are violating the Liskov Substitution Principle (LSP)... If `Products` need to do different things based on the concrete type of `IUnitOfWork` it would be violating the LSP. If that's the case, it sounds like that part should be refactored to a polymorphic Strategy. Can you perhaps post an example of what the `Add` method currently looks like?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this correctly, you want the client code to do this when `uow` is based on SQL Server:

```
uow.ProductRepo.Insert(new UserModel(){.....
uow.Save();
var uid = uow.ProductRepo.Get(u => u.someuniquecode == someUniqueCode)....... (etc)
```

but this when it's based on a Test Double:

```
var uid = uow.ProductRepo.Get(some lambda to get the largest ID) + 1
uow.ProductRepo.Insert(new UserModel(ID = uid, .......
```

However, that's not polymorphic behaviour. It violates the [Open Closed Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle), because it requires the client to know about available implementations, and it probably also violates the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), although I'm less sure about this.

Why not use the production interaction, and then implement `IUnitOfWork` correctly for both libraries?

If you really *must* have this different behaviour, then you should hide these differences behind a [Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), which again may act as a [Facade Service](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringtoAggregateServices) over `IUnitOfWork`. Then inject that Facade Service into `Products` instead of `IUnitOfWork`.